# Delphi - How to access a component into a Firefox window?

Tags: html, delphi, components

What I'm trying to do is accessing an editbox inside a webpage open in a firefox window. Finding the right firefox window I already can, the problem is accessing the edit box inside that webpage. I have no clue on how to do that.

These are from the source of the webpage and relate to the component I want to access:

```
<input name="Tit1" type="text" id="Tit1" class="campo" ... >
```

Comment: I see. Another idea is the program checking if webbrowser is indeed in the right webpage. The problem is that it can't be done by window name, since the name keeps always the same when I move thru the webpages of that website. So do you have any idea for that check? The program is to fill edit boxes in an specific webpage in firefox.

Comment: "Another idea is to just check if I am in the right page (webrowser page)". I don't know what that means.

Comment: Why do you want to automate Firefox?

Comment: because I'm tired of manually editing bar code to paste it into online bank website.

Comment: Why automate a webbrowser though? Why not use something like Indy? Or if you want to automate a browser, use one that has an easily accessible DOM. Like IE or Chrome. Both of which are trivial to drive inside Delphi.

Comment: I use Firefox. But since it's so complicated, let's make it with Chrome. How to do it in Chrome?

Comment: Host a TChromium browser control inside your Delphi process and use the DOM to drive the browser control.

Comment: and how to identify an specific edit box that way?

Comment: You'll find that our easily enough by reading up on DOM programming. There are hundreds of Qs on the topic here. Anyway, I don't want to give all the details in the comments when you asked a different question. It would have been much better if you had asked about your problem rather than your solution.